# Suma de Inputs JS diferente ID

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Hola buen dia a Todos.

Necesito generar una suma dependiendo de cuantos inputs la persona agregue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso me agrego 3 inputs.
Necesito que a la hora que haya un valor en el input VALOR TOTAL se SUME en el input
VALOR TOTAL MATERIALES.

Cada campo se crea cuando le da en el botón verde AÑADIR

Todos los inputs tienen un name, Id diferente.

La manera en que se crean estos campos es con js:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, binvenida a [es.so], podrías por favor agregar la manera en la que creas los inputs? tienen algun patron respecto al name o respecto al id?

Comment: ya lo añado a la pregunta

Comment: Hola, recuerda hacer el [tour], y revisa [ask]. El código no debe ser añadido como imagen, debe ser añadido como texto. Presiona "Editar" y pon tu código como texto.

Comment: @DianaBecerra, ¿No era más fácil copiar y pegar el código como texto, que andar sacando caputras de pantalla?

Comment: no me dejo pegar el código como es en realidad por eso me toco por capturas. OCmo tiene js y dentro tiene html me aparecia un error a la hora de subir el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Mediante una clase recorres todos los elementos que la tengan, en este caso los inputs de valor total, extraes su valor y los vas sumando para terminar imprimiendo tu suma final

```js
let valor_total_elems = document.querySelectorAll('.valor_total')
let suma = 0
valor_total_elems.forEach(e => suma += parseInt(e.value))

document.querySelector('#final').value = suma
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input id="1" type="number" value="10" class="valor_total"... />
  </div>
   <div>
    <input id="2" type="number" value="10" class="valor_total"... />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="3" type="number" value="10" class="valor_total"... />
  </div>
  <div><input id="final" type="number"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: podrias explicarme como un ejemplo porfavor

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Mas que una respuesta, esto parece un comentario. Mírate [answer] para aprender a realizar buenas respuestas, gracias.